# check user chooses an option from dropdown rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have a dropdown in which there is a `include_blank: "Select city"`. I want to write a code in which any city(excluding "Select city") is selected I want to `disable` some fields. But How can I check that any city is selected not `message` is selected.

```
<%= f.select 'city_id', grouped_options_for_select(cities), :include_blank: "Select city" , id: nil %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when $("#city_id").val() will give you blank and then you can recognize that select message is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If($("#city").val() == ""){
  console.log("");
}else{
 // your code
}
```